# Adding your own Automapper naming rule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

We use Automapper to map our Entities (from EF/database) to view models. Our project deals with an entity that has a relationship to a class called `Classification`, which has a bunch of properties that each have a `DisplayName` property.

Whenever we have a view model like this:

```
public class PersonViewModel{
  public string Nationality{get;set;}
  public string Gender {get;set;}
  public string HairColour {get;set;}   
}
```

And our entity may be (this is not a real example)

```
public class Person {
  public Classification Classification {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Classification {
  public Gender Gender {get;set;}
  public HumanHairColour HairColour {get;set;}
  public Nationality Nationality {get;set;}
}
```

and each of the property classes inside `Classification` has a `DisplayName` property like

```
public class Gender {
  public string DisplayName { get; set; }
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Nationality {
  public string DisplayName { get; set; }
  //...
}

public class HumanHairColour {
  public string DisplayName { get; set; }
  //...
}
```

Right now we have to manually add mappings for each of the properties on the `PersonViewModel` unless I want to name it `ClassificationNationalityDisplayName` or something silly like that.

Is it possible to add some sort of rule into our `Automapper` setup to ask it to check the `Classification` class for properties of similar names, and then to map it to a string use its `DisplayName` ?

Comment: Wouldn't `Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.Nationality, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Classification.Nationality.DisplayName))` work?

Comment: yes that maps it, we're using that at the moment, but I have to do that for every property on every view model across my application, I was hoping to make it a global rule

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the properties in your viewmodel to:

```
public class PersonViewModel {
  public string NationalityDisplayName { get; set; }
  public string GenderDisplayName { get; set; }
  public string HairColourDisplayName { get; set; }   
}
```

Then Automapper will map everything correctly with:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>();
```

Comment: wouldn't I need to name it ClassificationNationalityDisplayName? Which is a bit too long for me